# Windows CopyFileA fails then succeeds

Tags: c++, windows, file

I have an issue when trying to copy a file to a folder with specific permissions.

Here is my very simple test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    if(CopyFileA("D:/SOURCE/File.txt", "D:/LOCKED/dst1.txt", TRUE))
        std::cout << "OK\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Fail\n";

    if (CopyFileA("D:/SOURCE/File.txt", "D:/LOCKED/dst2.txt", TRUE))
        std::cout << "OK\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Fail\n";

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

And here is the result :

```
Fail
OK
```

I can copy as many files as I want. For each run, the first always fails and subsequents always succeed. The error is  ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Here is the important detail: my destination folder has restricted permissions and this behaviour occurs only if I remove "Write attributes" or "Write extended attributes".
[image]

I used sysInternals' Process Monitor: no other process is accessing source nor destination file. However, behaviour on destination file are not similar. The first attempt close the file and try to reopen it. Here are the logs:

| Action | Status | Details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **FAILED ATTEMP (FIRST)** | - | - |
| CreateFile | SUCCESS | Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Delete, Write DAC, Disposition: Create, Options: Sequential Access, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: 0, OpenResult: Created |
| CloseFile | SUCCESS |  |
| CreateFile | ACCESS DENIED | Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Delete, Write DAC, Disposition: OpenIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: 0 |
| CreateFile | ACCESS DENIED | Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Delete, Write DAC, Disposition: OpenIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 0 |
| CreateFile | ACCESS DENIED | Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Write DAC, Disposition: OpenIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 0 |
| CreateFile | ACCESS DENIED | Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: OpenIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: 0 |
| CreateFile | ACCESS DENIED | Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: OpenIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 0 |
| **SUCCEDDED ATTEMPT (SECOND AND SUBSEQUENTS)** | - | - |
| CreateFile | SUCCESS | Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Delete, Write DAC, Disposition: Create, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: 0, OpenResult: Created |
| QueryAttributeInformationVolume | SUCCESS | FileSystemAttributes: Case Preserved, Case Sensitive, Unicode, ACLs, Compression, Named Streams, EFS, Object IDs, Reparse Points, Sparse Files, Quotas, Transactions, 0x3c00600, MaximumComponentNameLength: 255, FileSystemName: NTFS |
| QueryBasicInformationFile | SUCCESS | CreationTime: 19/08/2021 15:20:32, LastAccessTime: 19/08/2021 15:20:32, LastWriteTime: 19/08/2021 15:20:32, ChangeTime: 19/08/2021 15:20:32, FileAttributes: A |
| SetEndOfFileInformationFile | SUCCESS | EndOfFile: 24 |
| WriteFile | SUCCESS | Offset: 0, Length: 24, Priority: Normal |
| ReadFile | SUCCESS | Offset: 0, Length: 24, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal |
| SetBasicInformationFile | SUCCESS | CreationTime: 01/01/1601 02:00:00, LastAccessTime: 01/01/1601 02:00:00, LastWriteTime: 19/08/2021 14:50:49, ChangeTime: 19/08/2021 14:50:49, FileAttributes: n/a |
| QueryRemoteProtocolInformation | INVALID PARAMETER |  |
| CloseFile | SUCCESS |  |

EDIT1:

Here is `get-acl D:\LOCKED | fl` response:

```
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\LOCKED
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : KJ-WIN10\None
Access : Everyone Allow  CreateFiles, AppendData, ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:BAG:S-1-5-21-1983668899-2794625975-2151939504-513D:PAI(A;OICI;0x1200af;;;WD)
```

You can reproduce full behaviour (folder creation and file copy) with my C# example program at https://github.com/KiwiJaune/CantMove/blob/master/Program.cs.

EDIT2:

Here is `fltmc` result on one of the several tested PCs:

| Filter name | Num Instances | Altitude | Frame |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bindflt | 1 | 409800 | 0 |
| FsDepends | 12 | 407000 | 0 |
| WdFilter | 12 | 328010 | 0 |
| storqosflt | 0 | 244000 | 0 |
| wcifs | 4 | 189900 | 0 |
| CldFlt | 2 | 180451 | 0 |
| aksdf | 12 | 145900 | 0 |
| FileCrypt | 0 | 141100 | 0 |
| luafv | 1 | 135000 | 0 |
| npsvctrig | 1 | 46000 | 0 |
| Wof | 8 | 40700 | 0 |
| FileInfo | 12 | 40500 | 0 |

I discover that it always fails on D:/ or flash drives, but succeeds on C:/, no matter if D: is another physical disk or a partition on the same disk as C: ...

I have the same behaviour on 4 PC tested (3 Win10 & 1 Win7)

Is there a Windows known behaviour ?
Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Comment: Yes sorry, it's ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. I edit the original message.

Comment: Did you try disabling your antivirus? If that is not the problem is D: a network drive or local?

Comment: In your other (now deleted) question, you said that it succeeds when copying/moving to a directory which does not have the restricted permissions.  In this other case, does Process Monitor still show that `CopyFileA` is doing the unexpected open-close-open?  (In other words, is the restricted permission causing the bad behavior, or does the bad behavior always occur and restricted permission turns it into a failure?)

Comment: (I deleted it to not duplicate since I have taken the problem in another way because it's not language specific, sorry for the confusion). Yes the process is similar when permissions are given : the file is close then reopen (but it works).

Comment: While I concur on the AV issue. I'd also try the unicode version of the method to see if that changes anything. I don't think it will, but sometimes the Ansi versions do weird things.

Comment: @drescherjm Sorry, didnt see your message. I have no antivirus, I try to disable Windows Defender too, and sysInternals' Process Monitor didn't notified any process accessing my files. D is a local drive.

Comment: @Mgetz Same behaviour with CopyFileW (and same in C# with File.Copy or File.Move, so it's not language specific I guess)

Comment: I assume you disabled inheritance initially, so all entries have "inherited from" as None and given you blanked out the principal, I guess you added your user explicitly with the shown permissions and then removed "authenticated users"? Can you add the output of: `get-acl D:\LOCKED | fl` to the question?

Comment: I edited the initial post with the get-acl response. The folder is created in C#. You can see how and reproduce the full issue with my C# example at https://github.com/KiwiJaune/CantMove/blob/master/Program.cs (Behaviour is the same when I configure the folder manually)

Comment: Can you post the output of `fltmc`?  You will need to run it from an admin prompt.  I'm wondering if a file system filter driver is causing this.

Comment: I edited with `fltmc`result. Moreover, I discover that it always fails on D:/ or flash drives, but succeeds on C:/, no matter if D: is another physical disk or a partition on the same disk as C: ...

I have the same behaviour on 4 PC tested (3 Win10 & 1 Win7)

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour when the Aksdf driver is not loaded? You might be able to run ‘fltmc unload aksdf’. Usually the driver and name are the same but they don’t have to be. You can always rename the aksdf.sys file and reboot as not all file system filter drivers can be unloaded.

Comment: I run `fltmc unload aksdf` in powershell and retried; same behaviour

Answer (score 2):

Moving a file from one location to another on the same drive just causes Windows to move its directory location; moving to a location on a different drive causes Windows to copy the file to the destination and then delete the original file.

When copying a file using the API, Windows appears to use two methods:

1. Windows create an empty destination file and then opens it to write the data.
2. Windows creates the file at the destination in write mode to add the data.

This is what is happening in your program: the first time you call to Move the file, Windows is using method 1... subsequent calls are using method 2.

The problem is that method 1 requires Modify permission on the directory. Effectively, Windows creates the empty file but cannot then open the file to add the data. This is borne out by the empty file that is being created in D:\LOCKING: giving Modify permission to the destination directory resolves this issue; alternatively, create the temporary files on the same drive as the intended destination.